# Runtime exception in android

Tags: android, exception, runtime, classcastexception

```
package com.androidbook.triviaquiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizSplashActivity extends TriviaQuizActivity{
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);
            Log.e("My App","Error Occured in on create1");
            startAnimating();
            Log.e("My App","Error Occured in on create1");

        }
     public void startAnimating() {
         try{
            TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
            logo1.startAnimation(fade1);

            Log.e("My App","Error Occured in start animating1");
            TextView logo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
            logo2.startAnimation(fade2);
            Log.e("My App","Error Occured in start animating2");
            fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
         public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // The animation has ended, transition to the Main Menu screen
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuizSplashActivity.this, QuizMenuActivity.class));
                    QuizSplashActivity.this.finish();
         }
         public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
         }
         public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
         }
            });
            Log.e("My App","Error Occured in start animating general");
            Animation spinin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
            LayoutAnimationController controller =
            new LayoutAnimationController(spinin);
            TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
            for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
            TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
            row.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
            Log.e("My App","Error Occured in start animating general end ");
            }
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             Log.e("Exception logged",ex.getStackTrace().toString());

         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         logo1.clearAnimation();

            Log.e("My App","Error Occured in onPause1");

         TextView logo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         logo2.clearAnimation();

            Log.e("My App","Error Occured in onPause1");
         TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
         for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
         TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
         row.clearAnimation();
         Log.e("My App","Error Occured in onPause3");
         }
     }
     @Override 
     public void onResume(){
         super.onResume();
         startAnimating();
     }

}
```

This is Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.androidbook.triviaquiz"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/quizicon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
      <activity android:name=".QuizSplashActivity" android:label="@string/splash">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizGameActivty" android:label="@string/game"></activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizHelpActivity" android:label="@string/help"></activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizMenuActivity" android:label="@string/menu"></activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizScoresActivity" android:label="@string/scores"></activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizsettingsActivity" android:label="@string/settings"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The Exception that is thrown in debug mode:

```
{com.androidbook.triviaquiz/com.androidbook.triviaquiz.QuizSplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
```

Layout File Splash activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@android:color/black" android:layout_weight="0.94" android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.08" android:text="@string/header" android:textColor="@color/logo_color" android:textSize="24pt" android:id="@+id/textView1"></TextView>
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_weight="0.48" android:weightSum="1" android:stretchColumns="*">
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash1" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash2" android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash3" android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash4" android:id="@+id/imageView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            </TableRow>
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@color/logo_color" android:fadeScrollbars="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:textSize="24pt" android:text="@string/footer" android:layout_weight="0.36"></TextView>
            </TableLayout>
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/version" android:background="@color/version_bkgrd" android:textColor="@color/version_color" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="32dp" android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/version_spacing"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please paste the entire exception like what line the exception is occurring on.

Comment: Edit your que and make it more understandable

Comment: Just look at the stack trace and find out in which line the exception was occurred. Most likely, after you find that out, you yourself will be able to find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Well, everything looks fine..but I still like to have you check two places:

1. Make sure your layout's file name really is splash
2. If you have previously named something else as textView1 or textView2, you might want to clean the project and rebuild from scratch